# View time range selection on datagrid with limited space

Tags: gui-design, interaction-design, user-expectation, design-patterns, design

I have a datagrid that shows realtime data. How ever, Users should select to see if they want 'Last 5 minutes' data or 'Real time' Data. I did this using radio buttons, however it doesn't fit and is not working.

[image]

What can i make it to do this better or minimalistic ?

Comment: You could use a tabs or pills - https://semantic-ui.com/modules/tab.html#/examples

Comment: @LucasRael What you mean by pills ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use a dropdown, you'll save space. Be aware that there are some tradeoffs.

[image]

Pro:

- saves space
- allows for additional choices (if extra ranges are added in the future)
- allows for longer label (since only one is shown at a time)

Con:

- only one choice shown at a time
- discoverability of the control

Because you can only see one choice, you could experiment by adding some graphic distinction to indicate interactivity. 
One way is to add a border. You can also experiment with color as well.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If choices fit into the space, use segmented controls:
[image]

If choices are more than the space allows, or more than 5, use drop down.

Segmented controls do not hide the filter options behind a click, all options are visible in the interface. However, as the number of options increase it starts becoming visually busy and hard to read, opt for the dropdown.